# Show duplicate rows

Tags: sql

I got a list with names and IP addresses like this:

```
ID | Name     | Address
1  | Peter    | 111.222.333
2  | John     | 999.888.333
3  | Hans     | 111.222.333
4  | Kimberly | 555.555.1111
```

I'm trying to find a way to display the duplicate accounts like this with SQL:

```
Name  | Second account (found by IP)
Peter | Hans
```

Please help,

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to join the table to itself.

```
select
t1.name, t2.name as second_account
from
your_table t1
inner join your_table t2 on t1.address = t2.address and t1.name < t2.name
```

Comment: `and t1.name <> t2.name`

Comment: And I was too quick, too. Better make it `and t1.name < t2.name` in order not to display the same users twice.

Comment: Holy, I better get some coffee. Thanks again.

Comment: Works great, thank you! Is this also an efficient way? Got more then 100.000 rows.

Comment: Well, you better have an index on (address, name). Then it should be super fast.

Answer (score 1):

If you got more than 2 duplicates

```
1  | Peter    | 111.222.333
2  | John     | 111.222.333
3  | Hans     | 111.222.333
```

fancyPants's query will return all possible combinations like

```
Name  | Second account (found by IP)
Peter | Hans
Peter | John
John  | Hans
```

This will return a list of duplicates, not pairs:

```
select address, name
from tab
where address in
  ( select address
    from tab
    group by address
    having count(*) > 1
  )
```

Depending on your needs this might be ok, too:

```
select min(name), max(name), count(*) as number_of_duplicates
from tab
group by address
having count(*) > 1
```